# Can I use vb.net to interrogate a website to know if it uses SSL

Tags: vb.net, http, url

I have a program that asks the user to type in a URL, and click *download*.   Then the program downloads the webpage.
However, some websites use *SSL*, and in that case the user has to prefix his URL with `https://` for this to work.

The problem is that the  user may not know whether the website uses *SSL*, and may type `http://...` instead of `https://....`
  Is there some way to send a preliminary message to the website (from vb.net) asking whether the URL should start with `https` or just `http`?  If there is, I can correct the user URL before attempting to retrieve the web page.

(I should say there it is not enough to use something like this:
 `request.RequestUri.Scheme` - this looks at the URL the user submitted, not the URL coming back from the server, as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

For websites that uses SSL, usually they will force the request to use HTTPS. That is when you send a request in HTTP, for example, http://www.example.com, the website will send a redirect response with HTTP status code 302 as well as the URL the client side that initiate the request should redirect user to.

So, you can try HTTP first and check the response  to see if there is a redirect. So, you will need to handle that in your code.

Comment: Or `301` -> Moved/MovedPermanently (`stackoverflow.com`, for example :). Or `403` -> Forbidden. Another way is to set the `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true` and inspect the `Response.ResponseUri` and see whether the `ResponseUri.Scheme` is `http` or `https` and check it against the Request Scheme. Most of the Web Sites perform this change silently, anyway. Or accept a http request (like `google.com`). The OP should also inspect the `Location` header (in case of a 301/302 status code), to verify if the a new destination address is completely different.